# JTextArea and JButton. Set the focus on the button

Tags: java, swing, focus, awt, jtextarea

The following program shows a `JTextArea` and a "Close" `JButton`. I defined the button as the default button because I would like it to have the focus as soon as I open the window. However, when I run the program the button is highlighted but the focus is on the text field.

How do I set the focus on the button and not the text area?

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;


public class Test {

    static JPanel southPanel;
    static JButton closeButton;
    static JFrame frame;
    static JTextArea textArea;
    private static final Dimension REASON_AREA_SIZE = new Dimension(250, 50);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String title = "";                                                                                                                                                                             
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setSize(1000, 800);
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setEditable(true);
        JScrollPane lScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        lScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        lScrollPane.setPreferredSize(REASON_AREA_SIZE);
        frame.add(lScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createSouthPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Here the close button is defined by default, the focus should be on it
        setDefaultButton();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle(title);                                                                                                                                                                          
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JPanel createSouthPanel() {
        southPanel = new JPanel(
                new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 10, 10));
        southPanel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
        addCloseButton(southPanel);
        return southPanel;
    }

    /**
     * Set the close button as default
     */
    protected static void setDefaultButton() {
        frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(closeButton);
    }

    private static void addCloseButton(JPanel pButtonsPanel) {
        closeButton = new JButton("Close");
        closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent pEvent) {
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });
        pButtonsPanel.add(closeButton);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `setDefaultButton()` method, add:

```
closeButton.requestFocus()
```

Focus is different to the default.

Comment: The problem is the same, the cursol is still in the JTextArea. I can't close the window by clicking on Enter

Comment: Not in front of an IDE right now, but try 'frame.getRootPane().closeButton.requestFocus()` - I suspect its not finding the close button correctly.

Comment: finally, closeButton.requestFocus() works if I put this at the end of the main function. Thanks